# Using webdav to selective sync Box on Ubuntu

Tags: sync, cloud, webdav

Following [various guides](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~gautam/sj/blog/20150807-box-webdav.html), I'm able to sync Box using WebDav. But my Box size is too large and I don't want to sync them all.

Is it possible to only sync certain folders using WebDav & Box?

[Box's WebDav help page](https://community.box.com/t5/Managing-Your-Content/Does-Box-support-WebDAV/ta-p/310) doesn't seem to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

The guide you link to, is mostly about WebDavfs2, though near the end it has a reference to an experimental sync client as well.  Did you try that?
I have tried various ways to sync my Box cloud.  Up to BoxSync3, I could sync with Wine.  That worked but I used Ubuntu on a dual boot laptop and when switching to windows the sync indexing started all over again, regardless of syncing under Ubuntu and vice-versa.
In the end I prefer to just have access to my files through WebDav, mounting the remote Box.com location.  The webdav client in Nautilus, performs better than webdavfs2, for that purpose.

I used the guide you link to and succeeded in mounting the remote Box.com location.  However it is very-very slow, with nautilus or most gui file managers - the client webdavfs2 caches icons and file information and with large cloud storage the system crawls till it hangs - there are plenty of posts on this problem.
Nautilus has a webdav client built in! use it and you will get much-much faster results (depending on your internet connection). Access to Box.com now works as fast as it does on my smart phone with the android client.
here is how:

1. Select "Connect to Server" at the bottom of your Nautilus side bar, or Nautilus > Files > Connect to Server
   [sidebar screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14CGV.png)
2. At the window prompting you to enter your webdav location enter
   `davs://dav.box.com:443`    (443 is the port)
   [screenshot of location query window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ60V.png)
3. Box will prompt you for user name and password

That's all for connecting and using your cloud files

In order to sync you will need a sync client.